# How did the word "Bollywood" originate?

Tags: cinema-history, terminology, indian-cinema

As we know, American film industry is referred as Hollywood. The American film industry is called so because the film industry emerged at the place called [Hollywood, Los Angeles, CA](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Hollywood,+Los+Angeles,+CA,+USA/@34.0938169,-118.3614977,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2bf07045279bf:0xf67a9a6797bdfae4!8m2!3d34.0928092!4d-118.3286614?hl=en)(Correct me if I am wrong). The place adopted the name Hollywood which is informally known as Tinseltown.

But my question is not about Hollywood but the [Hindi film Industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood). This is widely referred as Bollywood.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood) page of Bollywood:

> Bollywood is the sobriquet for India's Hindi language film industry, based in the city of Mumbai, Maharashtra. It is more formally referred to as Hindi cinema. The term "Bollywood" is often used by non-Indians as a synecdoche to refer to the whole of Indian cinema; however, Bollywood proper is only a part of the larger Indian film industry, which includes other production centres producing films in many other Indian languages. There is no place in India called Bollywood like the Hollywood.

Many people prefer calling it as Hindi film industry and against naming film industries with *wood*. There are other film industries in India too in other languages. Eg: Telugu film industry is named as Tollywood, Tamil industry is named Kollywood etc.,  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames) is the list of Hollywood inspired nicknames.

My question:

- Who is the creator of the word *Bollywood*?
- Since when did the word become popular?

Comment: I heard someone recently refer to the Jamaican film industry as Jollywood, & the Nigerian film industry as Nollywood. I guess there's no stopping it now :/  ...in fact I'm going to start calling American films made in London... Lollywood.

Comment: @Tetsujin I too came across that.on the internet while searching for some ID question.. That is what made me to post this question.

Comment: afaik, they are all back-formations. Once Bollywood was back-formed from Bombay/Hollywood, the rest were easy & came in a flurry recently.

Comment: OK, one more before I stop being silly... moves made at Pinewood shall henceforth be called Pollywood ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Pollywood is a real thing and refers to Pashto films, Punjabi film and sometime Pakistani films, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollywood,. And similarly  [Lollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lollywood) is a real term used for Pakistani films made in lahore

Comment: I knew once it started it would never stop ... OK, I'll have to rename them - British films can be **Brollywood** & Pinewood will just have to be **Plywood** :)

Comment: Instead of everyone listing names, just click on this link, and the comment section can be reduced to one line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2784/49).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Bollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood#Etymology) is a portmanteau (a blend of linguistic words), which is derived from Bombay (currently known as Mumbai) and Hollywood, California.

> The name "Bollywood" is a portmanteau derived from Bombay, India, (the former name for Mumbai) and Hollywood, California, the center of the American film industry. Bollywood does not exist as a physical place. Some deplore the name, arguing that it makes the industry look like a poor cousin to Hollywood.

This word was used in the 1970s by a writer of a magazine gossip column, but there is a disagreement on who used it first.

From [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-bollywood-3549901)

> The word was coined in the 1970s by the writer of a magazine gossip column, though there is disagreement as to which journalist was the first to use it.

As per [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-22349712)

> "The term Bollywood is an invention of the late 20th Century, after Bombay cinema caught the imagination of the West."

Perhaps, this term became popular at that time.

Comment: So the word itself is **inspired** from Hollywood ?

Comment: Yep. It seems so.

Comment: @Rahul Not directly. Bengal film industry is the first one to be named after a wood. HIndi industry took it from them

Comment: Interesting thing to note is that many are named after localities, not cities. Tollywood in bengal because films are shot in Tollygunge, Kolkata. Kollywood in TN because shooting happpens in Kodambakkam, Chennai.

Comment: I find this term very derogatory. But it is true in the sense that a majority of Indian films are rip-offs from Hollywood movies.