# Why do so many cinema industries have "wood" in their name?

Tags: film-industry, terminology

A lot of cinema industry names end with "wood". For example, [Kollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_cinema), [Bollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood), [Tollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollywood), [Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_of_the_United_States), etc.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: You might have forgotten to mention [Holy Wood](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Holy_Wood).

Comment: Why do so many cinema industries have **“ollywood”** in their name?

Comment: And Vinewood...

Comment: Thankfully Wellywood never took off .. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellywood

Comment: The point is not that they end in -wood but that they end in -ollywood. "Wood" on its own wouldn't indicate a whole lot, since it's a fairly common ending in English placenames.

Comment: As it turns out there are a LOT more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames

Comment: After ask this question, i have knew many names from comments and answers.

Comment: It's rather like "-gate". The first one was real, and the rest just used it as a pattern.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1) **Hollywood:** [1](https://blog.treepeople.org/environment/2012/12/hollywood-name), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood#Early_history_and_development)

> The name Hollywood was coined by H. J. Whitley, the “Father of
>   Hollywood.” Whitely bought 500 acres from E. C. Hurd; Hurd’s wife’s
>   friend (stay with me here), Daeida Wilcox, co-opted the name
>   “Hollywood” from her neighbor, Ivar Weid, who lived in what was then
>   called Holly Canyon.
>
> According to the diary of H. J. Whitley, known as the "Father of
>   Hollywood," on his honeymoon in 1886 he stood at the top of the hill
>   looking out over the valley. Along came a Chinese man in a wagon
>   carrying wood. The man got out of the wagon and bowed. The Chinese man
>   was asked what he was doing and replied, "**I holly-wood**," meaning
>   '**hauling wood**.' H. J. Whitley had an epiphany and decided to name his
>   new town Hollywood. "Holly" would represent England and "wood" would
>   represent his Scottish heritage. Whitley had already started over 100
>   towns across the western United States.

2) **Bollywood:** [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood#Etymology)

> The name "Bollywood" is a **portmanteau derived from Bombay** (the
>   former name for Mumbai) and Hollywood (in California), the center of
>   the American film industry.

3) **Tollywood:** [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood#Etymology)

> Dating back to 1932, "Tollywood" was the earliest Hollywood-inspired
>   name, referring to the Bengali film industry based in Tollygunge (in
>   Calcutta, West Bengal), whose name is reminiscent of "Hollywood" and
>   was the centre of the cinema of India at the time.[18] It was this
>   "chance juxtaposition of two pairs of rhyming syllables," Holly and
>   Tolly, that led to the portmanteau name "Tollywood" being coined.

4) **Kollywood:** [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_cinema)

> Kollywood is a colloquial term used to describe this industry, the
>   word being a portmanteau of Kodambakkam and Hollywood.

So basically, the "wood" part comes from the **hauling wood** part and everyone else formed by it by creating a *portmanteau* between the Hollywood and something with themselves.

Comment: about Kollywood @Nikhil?

Comment: Kodambakkam area + Hollywood

Comment: Don't forget [Nollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nollywood).

Comment: Pinewood... in [or these days near-ish to] a pine wood, literally. I'm still working on getting the London film industry dubbed **Brollywood**

Comment: To those who are going to comment with ollywood names, See [List of Hollywood inspired nicknames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames). We don't want 20 comments specifying each industry name.

Comment: @NikhilEshvar Is there someplace called Lollywood? I've heard it someplace

Comment: @Vishwa Check the wikipedia article in Nog Shine's answer. Lollywood does exist!

Comment: That's a lot of **woods** . Are there any without wood in the name?

Comment: You've missed Dollywood out too.

Comment: @MD-Tech Based on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames) article, I must have missed 30+ woods... It will be tiring to remember everything...

Comment: @NogShine True, but Nollywood has to be in there. It's larger than the actual Hollywood.

Comment: I checked the references for 1) and noticed the diary containing the story about the Chinese man "hauling wood" was actually that of Margaret Virginia Whitley Davis.  To be precise, the first reference doesn't support the Chinese man story whatsoever, but the second [Wikipedia] link does contain a link to the diary entry in question (the only actual source of such a story I can find).

Comment: @Tetsujin the *wood* in *Pinewood* is thus a coincidence and it's the only example here so far that's not a derivative of *Hollywood*. (You are of course referring to the original Pinewood studios; Pinewood studios Wales could be known as *Industrialestatewood* or *Mudflatwood* but there aren't exactly a lot of trees near there.)

Comment: Please move any further discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=movies.stackexchange.com) ....

Answer (score 12):

They are inspired from Hollywood, Los Angeles. Wikipedia gives a [full list of Hollywood inspired nick names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames).

> **Hollywood-inspired nicknames, most starting with the first letter(s) of the location and ending in the letters "-ollywood" or "-wood", have been given to various locations around the world with associations to the film industry - inspired by the iconic Hollywood in Los Angeles, California**, whose name has come to be a metonym for the motion picture industry of the United States. Some of the following names, however, did in fact exist before Hollywood.

Hollywood is a real place whereas the names like Bollywood, Tollywood, Kollywood do not exist in maps. They just indicate the names of the film industries.

These nicknames are usually formed by the Nickname of the Portmanteau of the place they are located or the language and -ollywood.

Bollywood : **B**ombay + H**ollywood**. [How did the word "Bollywood" originate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72568/48608) discusses the derivation of the how the word was formed in detail.

Kollywood : **K**odambakkam + H**ollywood**

Mollywood : **M**alayalam + H**ollywood**

Tollywood (Bengali) : **Tolly**gunge + Holly**wood**

Tollywood (Telugu) : **T**elugu + H**ollywood**

Ollywood = **O**diya + Ho**llywood**

Many industries are also nicknamed inspired from Hollywood which are found in the article linked above.